# Android: Loading a library and using it only for development branch not for release

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-class-loaders

**Problem Statement:**
I want to use a library only on development environment but not on release (app store release).
And I don't want that library to get built in release apk also.

**My appraoch:**

So, I have an environment setup like this:

Development -

1. Debug
2. Release

Store -

1. Debug
2. Release -> This goes to play store

In gradle I have added -

```
debugCompile 'com.some.library'
```

Which loads this library for **Development - Debug** and **Store - Debug**

And then I have created two Application classes,

1. **ApplicationWithoutDebugLibrary** extends MultiDexApplication - Application class which doesn't initializes the library.
2. **ApplicationWithDebugLibrary** extends ApplicationWithoutDebugLibrary - Application class Which initialises the library

And I have defined in gradle to load different Application file for different flavour.

```
productFlavors {
            Development {
                applicationId "xyzzzz"
                manifestPlaceholders = [application:"com.xyz.ApplicationWithDebugLibrary"]
            }
            store {
                applicationId "11111"
                manifestPlaceholders = [application:"com.xyz.ApplicationWithoutDebugLibrary"]
            }
}
```

And in manifest I have written this:

```
<application
    android:name="${application}"...
```

So, for Debug it is working fine but when I am building Store-Release/ Development-Release apk it is not able to compile ApplicationWithDebugLibrary.java, as I am using the library, which is not compiled in gradle file for release flavour.

So, is there any way in which we can avoid loading this class for Store release flavour, or any alternate solution in which I can load that library only in Development environment.

Answer (score 2):

> So for Debug it is working fine but when I am building Store-Release/ Development-Release apk it is not able to compile ApplicationWithDebugLibrary.java, as I am using the library, which is not compiled in gradle file for release flavour

By logic there's no way to magically remove library your code uses and still have all remainings properly compile as there're simply missing symbols. So you must create "dummy" library, with the same API as your debug one but with no methods body. Alternatively you can wrap your lib with some code that can be later swapped for production with version that uses no library dependencies.

Android Gradle plugin can help building with different version of dependencies based of what type of build it is:

> The compile configuration is used to compile the main application.
>   Everything in it is added to the compilation classpath and also
>   packaged in the final APK. There are other possible configurations to
>   add dependencies to:
>
> - compile: main application
> - androidTestCompile: test application
> - debugCompile: debug Build Type
> - releaseCompile: release Build Type.

docs: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup

Comment: What about dynamic loading of classes and writing script in gradle to do the same.
I don't know whether its possible or not, I have read about it at lots of places, just curious to know.

Comment: Please rephrase your comment. I got no clue what you mean really.

Comment: I am asking, can we do this using dynamic classes loading or writing script in gradle for compiling a class based on some condition ?

Comment: Your only problem is that when you build for release your code is incomplete (missing libs). But again, build flavors should be sufficient to solve this and as I wrote - either have `no-op` version of your debug lib for release builds so all methods are available regardless what you build or bridge that lib with separate class and then swap the classes on build (again, with build flavors).