# Changing my sources according on the build parameters

Tags: android, gradle, preprocessor

TL;DR: What would be a clean way to change my sources depending on the parameters passed to gradle?

---

I am building an Android application which has a dependency on the library `A`. I'd like to be able to support several versions of `A` (let's say I want to support both `v1` and `v2`). By that I mean that I want to be able to build both a `myapp-withAv1.apk` and a `myapp-withAv2.apk`.

I've seen that it's easy to select at compile time the version of `A` I want (I can for instance refer to this version in a variable in my `build.gradle` file and then launch a build with `./gradlew -PversionOfA=v1 build`).

But an other difficulty is that `A` can change its public API so I would need to change my code according to the version I'm building against. It would be easy if I was doing C++ or C# (thanks to `#ifdef`) but I haven't been able to find a way to do it without too much code duplication and I would be extatic if you can point me at a way to achieve it.

(Note that trying to isolate code branch with something like `if(version == v1)` doesn't work since it would lead to a code branch that would call a method of `A` which isn't available, so the build would fail)

Comment: Related: [Android: Loading a library and using it only for development branch not for release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43201205/295004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into a similar problem the answer is `productFlavors` in android or `sourceSets` for a generic jar.  Basically you need to specify an implementation to an interface in each sourceset.

```
# define the interface in the main
/src/main/java/com/me/IMyInterface.java
# create a v1 and v2 sourceset with the implementation, note paths are the same
/src/v1/java/com/me/MyImplementation.java
/src/v2/java/com/me/MyImplementation.java
```

Now in your gradle define the productFlavors

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        v1 {
            buildConfigField 'string', 'FLAVOR', 'v1'
        }
        v2 {
            buildConfigField 'string', 'FLAVOR', 'v2'
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Now when you reference the implementation you will get the `sourceSet` for the version defined as the product flavor name.

```
// since the package is the same we are unaware of which we are calling
// now we can treat them as the same regardless of the underlying
// implementation differences between v1/v2

import com.me.MyImplementation;

public String doSomethingWithImplementation() {

    MyImplementation impl = new MyImplementation();

    // here if we are executing in the productFlavor v1
    // apk we get the code from the v1 folder, same for v2 apk
    return impl.doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar needs when developed for J2ME in 2002 so that developed [a preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor), today it has support for maven,gradle and ant, you can try it for android, a test android project which can be used as sample [can be found in the project repository](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/tree/master/jcp-tests/jcp-test-android)
In case of preprocessor, [Java sources look like that](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/ExampleOfUseWithJ2ME)